# jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__(...).popover is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have Angular 2 project with installed bootstrap and jquery. I've included both bootstrap and jquery in the project via the scripts field in angular.json like so:

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",              
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
]
```

The reason I included bootstrap.bundle is because popper, as suggested by the bootstrap documentation.

I also use OpenLayers, and in the ngOnInit method I have the following code:

```
const element = document.getElementById('popup');

var popup = new OlOverlay({
  element: element,
  positioning: 'bottom-center',
  stopEvent: false
});

this.map.addOverlay(popup);

this.map.on('click', (evt) => {
  var feature = this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function (feature, layer) {
      return feature;
    });
  if (feature) {
    var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
    var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();
    popup.setPosition(coord);
    $(element).popover({
      'placement': 'top',
      'html': true,
      'content': feature.get('name')
    });
    $(element).popover('show');
  } else {
    $(element).popover('destroy');
  }
});
```

and the html:

```
<div id='map-stations' class='map'><div id='popup'></div></div>
```

However, whenever I click on the map's feature, I get the following error:

```
jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__(...).popover is not a function
```

I have jquery included as follows:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@mkorunoski don't worry, follow my steps

1) Install jQuery. (skip if already installed)

```
npm install jquery --save
```

2) Install types for jQuery.

```
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

3) Import jQuery in **app.module.ts.**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

4) Install bootstrap 3 not 4, so remove your bootstrap.bundle.min.js in **angular.json**

```
npm install bootstrap@3 --save
```

5) Add correct injection in **angular.json**, the order is important

```
"scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

6) in the file where you use openlayers & popover add this after the imports

```
    declare var $: any;
```

7) now you can use

```
    $(element).popover('show');
```